# Ajax load cause jump Issue and flickering issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have five tabs.
On clicking a tab, loading the content through ajax (.load()). Each tab content varies. Which cause the browser to jump. 
Is there any possibility to avoid these jump ?
I tried `min-height` but content height varies dynamically so setting it cause empty space on the page also.
This issue occurs only once.If I again click on the same tab,then there will be no jump.

Flickering,
Tab content have images. It cause flickering too.

Kindly share your thoughts to overcome these jump & flickering.

Adding code:

```
jQuery("#tabs a").click(function(event){
    var url_to_load = jQuery(this).attr('href');

    jQuery( ".tab-content-wrapper" ).load(url_to_load+" .tab-content-wrapper", function( response, status, xhr ) {
    var head = response.match(/<meta[^>]*>[\s\S]/gi);
    jQuery("meta").remove();
    jQuery("head").prepend(head);


    }); 

});`
```

Comment: Can you show your code? Including the HTML

Answer (score 0):

try using Ladda or load all the tabs content previously (lazy load if it is lots of data) and just change it trought tabs preventing defaults